# Concept of instantiating

Tags: c#, inheritance, instantiation

If we have this:

```
class Car
{
    public void mCar()
    {

    }

}

class Audi : Car
{
    public void mAudi()
    {

    }
}
```

and in some other class, we have:

```
Car x = new Audi();
```

then we only have access to mCar(), but not to mAudi().
My question is, what is the difference between:

Car x = new Audi();

and

Car x = new Car();

Comment: Where's `mKola()` coming from?

Comment: @voidStern I'm sorry, I don't use English in my programs and when I write here I always forgot to translate something. It's edited now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is

```
Car = new Car();
```

gives you a new Car object (it knows only of `mCar()`), while

```
Car = new Audi();
```

gives you a new Audi object, which is also a car object (it knows of `mCar()` and `mAudi()`).

Comment: But if it's a Audi object, then why it can't access mAudi() ?

Comment: @user966638: It *can*. You can't write `x.mAudi()`, because the reference `x` is itself of type `Car`, but you can write `((Audi)x).mAudi()`, which casts `x` to type `Audi`. By contrast, if you had `Car x = new Car();`, then `((Audi)x)` would not be valid. (Note: the details of this depend on the language. Your code looks like C#, so I've gone with that.)